# Numerical stability of advection equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, stability-in-odes

So I have the pde $u_t + (vu)_x =0$ , $x \epsilon $R, t>0

and $u(x,0)=u_0(x)$ , $x \epsilon $R. as well as $u_j^0 =u_0(x_j)$ and $v_j =v(x_j)$

and I have to discuss the stability of this:

$\frac{u_j^{n+1} -u_j^n}{\Delta t} +v_j \frac{u_j^n -u_{j-1}^n}{h} +u_j^n \frac{v_j -v_{j-1}}{h} =0$

To do that I think that I have to prove that

$sup_{x\epsilon R} |u(x,t)| \leqslant sup_{x\epsilon R}|u_0(x)|$   is true

which I'm pretty sure i've managed through induction and the triangle inequalities..

I know that it is the advection equation ish, and I think its the backwards version of it.

I have tried rearranging the formula for = $u_j^{n+1}$ and I don't think that helped.

Should I show that that formula equals the supremum formula? but even then I don't know how that would explain whether or not it is stable.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: This scheme is an upwind FD discretization of $u_t + v u_x + u v_x = 0$. If $v > 0$ is constant, one recognizes the classical [upwind scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upwind_scheme), which is stable under the CFL condition $v \Delta t / h \leq 1$ (proof using Von Neumann analysis, or showing that $\|{\bf u}^{n+1}\|_1 \leq \|{\bf u}^{n}\|_1$).

Comment: Thanks, I understand that part now, however do you know how to tell the stability if my velocity is changing? e.g $v'(x)>0$ and $ v \in C^1(ℝ)$